# oracle date issue

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, plsql

I have a table called `ORDER` with column `cancel_date_time`. I am using:

```
to_char(cancel_date_time,'YYYYMMDD HH24:MI:SS')
    not between ('20120214 10:00:00')
            and ('20120215 10:00:00')
```

to retrieve records. But is it not returning any records when `cancel_date_time` is `NULL`.

Can any one advise what is the issue to retrieve records?

Comment: You appear to not know what you are trying to achieve.  Null does not have a value so before you ask how to code for null values, you have to know what you want to do if they exist.  Also, using to_char like that will slow down your query.  Use real datetime parameters instead.

Comment: @Dan:Yeah I dont know this particular case,Can you please give me some hint

Comment: if you are doing this for someone else, and you are unsure of the requirements, ask that person.

Comment: @Dan: if you understand the question correctly,what i am saying is not returning any records when `cancel_date_time` is `NULL`.it means condition not between is faling.It doesn't mean that if cancel_date_time is null to bring the records

Comment: I don't understand the last comment.  Simple question - if the cancel datetime is null, should your query return that record?  Yes or no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Null is not a value so it's not comparable to other values.

You could use such construction:

```
    ...
    where
      nvl (cancel_date_time, date_value_for_empty_cancel_date) 
      not between ('20120214 10:00:00') and ('20120215 10:00:00')
```

Also string literals for dates are NLS-dependable and to_char will probably prevent to use an index.

Comment: :date_value_for_empty_cancel_date .what value it should have.

Comment: Either value in your searched range, if you want to exclude non-cancelled orders from result or value outside the range, if those records must be included.

It depends on your business logic.

Comment: This is good idea.  nvl (cancel_date_time, to_date('20120101 11:00:00','YYYYMMDD HH24:MI:SS) )
      not between ('20120214 10:00:00') and ('20120215 10:00:00').But giving error

Comment: Is cancel_date_time a char type, not date? Also there is missing quote after HH24:MI:SS

Comment: I would try to replace literals ('20120214 10:00:00') with to_date expressions with explicit format.

Comment: There is no missing quotes

Comment: I meant this: http://take.ms/zUJ7E but it's not an issue. Try replace date literals with to_date(...,'YYYYMMDD HH24:MI:SS').

Comment: sorry it's not missing actually .when i type it here quote is nissing.

Comment: where 
 nvl (cancel_date_time, to_date('20120101 11:00:00','YYYYMMDD HH24:MI:SS) ) 
 not between to_date ('20120214 10:00:00','YYYYMMDD HH24:MI:SS') 
          and to_date ('20120215 10:00:00','YYYYMMDD HH24:MI:SS')

Answer (score 1):

If you want the rows where `cancel_date_time` is `NULL` along with any rows where `cancel_date_time` is not between two dates

```
WHERE cancel_date_time NOT BETWEEN to_date( '20120214 10:00:00','YYYYMMDD HH24:MI:SS') 
                               AND to_date( '20120215 10:00:00','YYYYMMDD HH24:MI:SS')
   OR cancel_date_time IS NULL
```

You don't want to apply functions to columns that can potentially be indexed.  And if you want date comparison semantics, you want to compare dates to dates.  Finally, since `NULL` is never equal to and never unequal to any other value, you need an explicit check for `IS NULL`.

Comment: My scenaio is not retrieve records even if date is null

Comment: @user2113371 - The query you posted in your question will not return rows where `cancel_date_time` is `NULL`.  In your question, you are saying that this is a problem and you want to retrieve those rows.